# NewtonSoft Json Deserialize two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON.

```
[["NAME","S0101_C01_008EA","S0101_C01_031M","state","county"],
["Alcona County, Michigan",null,"1.1","26","001"],
["Alger County, Michigan",null,"1.7","26","003"],
["Allegan County, Michigan",null,"0.2","26","005"],
["Alpena County, Michigan",null,"0.9","26","007"],
["Antrim County, Michigan",null,"0.9","26","009"],
["Arenac County, Michigan",null,"0.8","26","011"]]
```

I'm trying to deserialize it into an array of objects. I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time.

I can get the info I need using .

```
 Dim PopulationByState As List(Of JArray) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of JArray))(response)

Dim lst As New List(Of String) 'create a new list to hold the strings

For Each t As JToken In PopulationByState

    For Each i In t.Children()

        ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
    Next

Next
```

Comment: You seem to have an open string in your code sample. Also, what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may deserialize it to a `List(Of List(Of Object))`:

```
Dim PopulationByState As List(Of List(Of Object)) = _
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of List(Of Object)))(response)

Dim state As List(Of Object)
For Each state In PopulationByState.Skip(1) ' .Skip(1) to skip the header '
    ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Join(vbTab, state))
Next
```

Demo (with output to console instead of filling a list box): https://dotnetfiddle.net/XQ3w2Z